# WPF link controls together in GridView

Tags: wpf, binding

I have the following:

```
<ListView Name="lstStepTargets" Margin="0,3,0,-3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="Enabled" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Enabled, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="TargetPath" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Width="auto" Text="{Binding Path=BaseFolder}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="IgnoreFilter" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=IgnoreFilter}" Name="txtIgnore" MinWidth="100" Width="Auto"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="IncludeFilter" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=IncludeFilter}" Name="txtInclude" MinWidth="100" Width="Auto"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Apply Filter to All" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Apply" Click="ButtonClick" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In the handler for the button I need an elegant way to get access to:

> A.  The text in txtIgnore and txtInclude for "this" row.
>
> B.  The data context for "this" row. (I may just need this one)

Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataContext` is inherited, hence you should be able to get the DataContext of the row from the button:

```
MyData data = (sender as Button).DataContext as MyData;
```

The `MyData`-object should have the values you input in the TextBoxes in the properties `IgnoreFilter` and `IncludeFilter` since you bound those.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are Binding txtIgnore and txtInclude it means you have that property in the DataContext behind, so you can use the same datacontext from inside your button handler.